# is it possible to set hidden field value using jquery in grails?

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

I need to perform some operation using javascript to set the value of a hiddenfield.

```
<g:hiddenField name="city" value="" />
```

So onclick of a button I should set value of 'city' based on js function call.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

```
$("input[name='city']").val("some value to set here");
```